# Bounds for a finite alternating sum

Tags: inequality, summation

This is probably a simple question, but I just wanted to be sure.

Say, we have a finite alternating sum: $$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^{n+1} a_n$$

Where the terms are decreasing in absolute value: $$0<a_n<a_{n-1}$$

For an even number of terms it's easy to show that for any integers $q<p$:

$$S_{2q}<S_{2p}< S_{2q+1}$$

But for an odd number of terms we will also have to consider the last term:

$$S_{2q}+a_{2p+1}<S_{2p+1}< S_{2q+1}+a_{2p+1}$$

Is the above correct?

Comment: @Scientifica, I don't have any proof to verify here, are you sure this tag is needed?

Comment: Hmm you're right. I'll remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p > q$ you have
$$
 S_{2p} - S_{2q} = \sum_{j=q+1}^p (a_{2j-1} - a_{2j}) > 0
$$
and
$$
 S_{2p+1} - S_{2q+1} = \sum_{j=q+1}^p (-a_{2j} + a_{2j+1}) < 0
$$
and therefore
$$
  S_{2q} < S_{2p} < S_{2p+1} < S_{2q+1} \, .
$$

---

Your estimate $S_{2q}+a_{2p+1}<S_{2p+1}$ is equivalent to
$S_{2q+1}<S_{2p+1}$ and therefore wrong.

The other estimate $S_{2p+1}< S_{2q+1}+a_{2p+1}$ is correct, 
but holds even without the additional term $a_{2p+1}$ on the 
right-hand side.

Comment: So, the same bounds hold as for infinite series. I see, thank you

Comment: @YuriyS: Usually the bounds is shown for the partial sums first, then the limit is taken to show that it holds for the infinite series as well.